# Is there a prefered name for the “effective access time” formula?

Tags: terminology, computer-architecture, cpu-cache

Any CS class about caches will at some point address this classical formula (or a variant of it)

```
Effective_access_time = hit_time + miss_penalty * miss_rate
```

My question is simple: **does this formula have a "name" ?** (i.e. unambiguous, and ideally, well-accepted too). I found plenty of references to many *variants* of that concept. I'd like to know whether there exists one name to denote them all. By the way, the question makes sense : there are plenty of variants of the following sentence...

> In any square triangle, the square of the length of the hypotenuse is equal
>   to the sum of the squares of the lengths of the two shorter sides.

...but we prefer to refer to them all by the name "Pythagoras' theorem".

Comment: The ACM/IEEE-CS Curricula (page 46) refers to this concept as "computing Average Memory Access Time". So I guess I could go with "AMAT formula". It's maybe not well-accepted but at least it's unambiguous and easy to remember...